# How to automatically hide the console when executing a Python code?

Tags: python, cmd, popup

I am trying to make a Python code to automatically shut off processes that are not vital to the computer when the system starts to heat up at a certain threshold, but when testing this code to see if it works, the CMD kept popping up when the code was running. Is there a way in Python to automatically hide the CMD when the code is running? I would think that the code would look something like this:

```
os.system(hide-window)
```

Comment: Just terminate the programs in Python. The process class has a terminate method. See https://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/python/0413/